# how does git know there is a conflict

Tags: git, git-merge

So there is master that goes

```
   m1->m2
```

and a branch that goes

```
     m1->m2
       \
        ->b1->b2
```

I did a merge of master into branch making it

```
   m1->m2         mb(merge commit)
        \       /
         ->b1->b2
```

Say i have had a conflict in one file that i fixed in branch while merging master. i fixed it and it now looks nothing like how the file looks in master ( at commit m3). if i merge the branch ( now at commit mb) back into master, git does not complain that there is a conflict. is the file not different? how does it know its not a conflict and it needs to use the file coming from the branch ?

I get that its the right behavior but i am just curious what tells git that the one in branch is the 'right' one.

Comment: The fixed conflict is merged into master so the conflict is fixed.

Comment: **roughly**, It's a matter of checking the differences that the separate branches introduced against _the last common ancestor_. When you merge master into branch X, when you try to merge X into master, the last common ancestor between both branches would be **master** (if it hasn't moved). So whatever changes you introduced into X will have to be put into master as a result of that merge.

Comment: The common ancestor is the last common commit where the file is the same in both branches? so when i did a merge of master into branch did the last common commit change for the file?

Comment: Your diagrams are inconsistent and make no sense and there is no m3. Please fix the diagrams to clarify the question. Thanks.

Comment: See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44359334/1256452) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50567245/1256452) as well. The lack of a conflict *after* merging is a result of the updated merge base, as [matt answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67780209/1256452).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thing to know: what is a merge? It is a combination of the changes in both branches *since the merge base* (ie where the branches "diverged" most recently).

> "what tells git that the one in branch is the 'right' one."

That is the whole point of "reverse" merges. Imagine this situation:

```
 mergebase
     |
A -- B -- C <- master
     \
      X <- branch
```

At this moment, B is the merge base if you merge either way between the two branches. Assume that both C and X change the same file in such a way as to generate a potential merge conflict. OK, so you merge `master` into `branch` and fix the conflict in that file (forming merge commit M in the diagram below). This also *moves the merge base* to the tip of `master` (C), in preparation for the upcoming forward merge:

```
      mergebase
          |
A -- B -- C <- master
     \    \
      X -- M <- branch
```

Hopefully, when you do then merge `branch` into `master`, `master` is unchanged *since the merge base C* (at least with respect to this file). Thus `master` makes *no contribution* since the merge base, but `branch` does (the merge commit M has a different version of the file than C does), so only `branch` contributes to the merge and its version of the file is adopted.

Comment: That makes sense, I did not realize that an activity in the branch ( a merge) would also further the merge base on the source branch ( master). Thanks for taking the time.