# Why changes in another line arise git merge conflict?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-merge-conflict

I modified different lines in different branches, but those changes occur `git merge` conflict.
I read [the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42693608/when-exactly-does-a-git-merge-conflict-arise), but I think the changes occur in totally different lines.

Here are my test codes.

#### branch-base

```
Hello, my first conflict.
Second line.a    # add a single character 'a' at line 2
Third line.
```

#### branch-a

```
Hello, my first conflict.
Second line.
Third line.a    # add a single character 'a' at line 3
```

And I executed the following code, it says git merge conflict.

```
$ git checkout branch-base
$ git merge branch-a
```

Here's my conflict file.

```
Hello, my first conflict.
<<<<<<< HEAD
Second line.a
Third line.
=======
Second line.
Third line.a
>>>>>>> branch-a
```

Why this conflict happens? I think I made changes in totally different lines (although those are adjacent.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There has to be at least a single line of separation that remains the same so that they can be treated separately and not produce a conflict. Given that they are not separated by a line that stays the same on all 3 revisions (the two tips *and* the common ancestor) then they are treated as a single block. One branch modifies that block one way, the other in another way... so, conflict.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you give me the document for 'at least a single line of separation' rule?

Comment: Here is a little something I wrote, hope it's informative enough. It has a conflict where you can see how having a single line of separation skips the conflict: http://www.ezconflict.com/en/conflictsse6.html

Comment: I found this comment today. Thanks.