# github merge conflict and resolve conflicts button disabled

Tags: git, github

I am new programmer and new to github this is the first time we are doing group project.we get merge conflict error and reveal merge disabled
[See The Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lID6.jpg)

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. On that screenshot, Github provided a link to what to do on the command line, along with some explanation/examples at the bottom of your PR. Or are you asking for a general ["What is a merge conflict?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42693608/2745495). There is also the [How to resolve merge conflicts in a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/161813/2745495).

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the conflicts are too big. You can do it manually in the terminal.

```
git checkout base-branch
git pull 
git checkout brach-that-you-want-to-merge
git merge base-branch
```

Now all the conflicts will be displayed in the code and you can choose which version you want to keep.