# How to resolve a git conflict by keeping all additions from both sides?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase, merge-conflict-resolution, git-merge-conflict

I keep running into the following problem and I'd like to know whether there is an easy solution to it using existing git commands or whether I'll need to [write a custom merge driver](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_defining_a_custom_merge_driver).

Here's an example to demonstrate my problem: Say the `master` branch of my repo has the following file:

```
$ cat animal.hpp 
#include <string>

class Animal
{
public:
  virtual std::string say() const = 0;
};
```

I create a new branch called `mybranch` and make the following change:

```
diff --git a/animal.hpp b/animal.hpp
index e27c4bf..3bb691a 100644
--- a/animal.hpp
+++ b/animal.hpp
@@ -5,3 +5,13 @@ class Animal
 public:
   virtual std::string say() const = 0;
 };
+
+class Dog : public Animal
+{
+public:
+  virtual std::string
+  say() const override
+  {
+    return "woof";
+  }
+};
```

In the meantime, someone else adds the following, very similar change to `master`:

```
diff --git a/animal.hpp b/animal.hpp
index e27c4bf..310d5a7 100644
--- a/animal.hpp
+++ b/animal.hpp
@@ -5,3 +5,13 @@ class Animal
 public:
   virtual std::string say() const = 0;
 };
+
+class Cat : public Animal
+{
+public:
+  virtual std::string
+  say() const override
+  {
+    return "meow";
+  }
+};
```

Now when I try to merge `mybranch` with `master` (or rebase `mybranch` onto `master`), I get a conflict:

```
$ cat animal.hpp 
#include <string>

class Animal
{
public:
  virtual std::string say() const = 0;
};

<<<<<<< HEAD
class Dog : public Animal
=======
class Cat : public Animal
>>>>>>> master
{
public:
  virtual std::string
  say() const override
  {
<<<<<<< HEAD
    return "woof";
=======
    return "meow";
>>>>>>> master
  }
};
```

The correct resolution to this conflict is:

```
$ cat animal.hpp 
#include <string>

class Animal
{
public:
  virtual std::string say() const = 0;
};

class Dog : public Animal
{
public:
  virtual std::string
  say() const override
  {
    return "woof";
  }
};

class Cat : public Animal
{
public:
  virtual std::string
  say() const override
  {
    return "meow";
  }
};
```

I've created the above resolution by manually editing the file, duplicating the code that is common to the two classes, and removing the conflict markers. But I think git should be able to create this resolution automatically, given that it only needs to add all the lines that were added in one branch, followed by all the lines that were added in the other branch, without deduplicating common lines. How can I make git do this for me?

(Bonus points for solutions that allow me to customize the order - `Dog` first or `Cat` first.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There *is* a thing called a [*union merge*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13264117/1256452):

```
$ printf 'animal.hpp\tmerge=union\n' > .gitattributes
$ git merge --no-commit mybranch
Auto-merging animal.hpp
Automatic merge went well; stopped before committing as requested
```

In this particular case, it actually achieves the desired results.  However, in many cases it can misfire rather badly, and it *never fails* (I mean it never considers itself to *have* failed, even if it produced a nonsense result), so it's not really wise to set it up in `.gitattributes` after all (unless you have a really rare case).

Instead, it's better to invoke it after the fact, using [`git merge-file`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-file):

```
$ git merge --abort
$ rm .gitattributes
$ git merge mybranch
Auto-merging animal.hpp
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in animal.hpp
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
$ git show :1:animal.hpp > animal.hpp.base
$ git show :2:animal.hpp > animal.hpp.ours
$ git show :3:animal.hpp > animal.hpp.theirs
$ mv animal.hpp.ours animal.hpp
$ git merge-file --union animal.hpp animal.hpp.base animal.hpp.theirs
```

Make sure the result is what you wanted, then clean up a bit and add the final merged version:

```
$ rm animal.hpp.base animal.hpp.theirs
$ git add animal.hpp
```

and you are now ready to commit the result.  **Edit:** Here's the result I got (in both cases):

```
$ cat animal.hpp 
#include <string>

class Animal
{
public:
  virtual std::string say() const = 0;
};

class Cat : public Animal
{
public:
  virtual std::string
  say() const override
  {
    return "meow";
  }
};

class Dog : public Animal
{
public:
  virtual std::string
  say() const override
  {
    return "woof";
  }
};
```

Comment: I tried both these solutions, but they don't do exactly what I want.  They both produce the same merged file, which has the lines "class Dog : public Animal" and "class Cat : public Animal" right next to each other instead of having two separate class definitions.

Comment: Curious. I can add the actual resulting merged file, if you like: it looks correct to me.

Comment: That would be nice if you could add the merged file.  Thanks!

Comment: Wow, that's exactly what I want!  But that's not what it does on my machine.  Maybe my git is too old?  I'm on version 2.14.1.

Comment: That's the same version. I do have `merge.conflictstyle` set to `diff3` but I doubt that influences Git here. Ultimately the problem is that union merge works on a line-at-a-time basis and you have no control over which order lines are selected, and I was expecting it to misfire here too, but it actually worked, and I was surprised (changed answer mid-stream!).

Comment: That's indeed very strange...  As for union merge being potentially dangerous and uncontrollable, yes, I've read that too.  But if it solves my problem, it would be worth the risk for me.

Answer (score 6):

Git *can't* handle that kind of merge for you in typical workflows.  That's *why* it's asking you to intervene.  It's trying very, very hard not to lose changes from either side, but it doesn't really know how you want to resolve it or how you want to fix it.

You should look into a merge tool to help aid you with this.  Alternatively, you can do this manually and remove the Git merge conflict lines, and handle the merge of these two files yourself.

Comment: It's kind of silly that git can't handle this kind of change because the logic is pretty trivial. Mark position A, insert text from first commit directly before position A, then insert text from second commit between the end of first commit and position A (or, directly in front of position A)

Comment: @WayneWerner: It's *not* trivial, which is exactly why it can't resolve it.  Git cannot intuit what your intent is when you give it two different versions, nor should it blindly assume that you want to keep both versions.  It could be work you and someone else had done, for instance, and Git shouldn't keep track of who made what change to intuit some behaviors out of it.