# Why editing two different lines result in merge conflict in git?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-merge-conflict

I have  a single text file,  in initial commit

```
Line1
Line2
```

I created branch from master, and committed this changes

```
Line1-b1
Line2
```

Finally I checkout to master and created this commit,

```
Line1
Line2-b2
```

When I try to merge to master , I got the following merge conflict, why? since the two lines are different, I was not expecting merge conflict.

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
Line1
Line2-m
=======
Line1-b1
Line2
>>>>>>> b1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does git produce a merge conflict when lines next to each other are changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29276880/why-does-git-produce-a-merge-conflict-when-lines-next-to-each-other-are-changed)

Comment: @mkrieger1 it does not answer my question.

Comment: Then maybe [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42693608/when-exactly-does-a-git-merge-conflict-arise)?

Comment: @mkrieger1 NO, I need answer.

Comment: The answers are attached to the duplicate questions.