# Understanding git revert conflict

Tags: git

For a test-file I made several changes and commited them.
In order for everyone to follow these changes, here is the output of git log -p:

```
commit 6d1ab83bd1b9fbe0b0953eeb209afec90f592b7d (HEAD -> main)

    a further line

diff --git a/test.txt b/test.txt
index 987fb68..9692e29 100644
--- a/test.txt
+++ b/test.txt
@@ -4,4 +4,6 @@ here i am

 i have never been there

+a further line
+


commit 35f743c6ae1835182691729eaf447b09337d2ed6

    hello -> hio and newline added

diff --git a/test.txt b/test.txt
index c511e9f..987fb68 100644
--- a/test.txt
+++ b/test.txt
@@ -1,5 +1,7 @@
-hello
+hio

 here i am

+i have never been there
+
```

I then called git revert 35f743c in order to undo some previous changes. This resulted in a merge conflict. After viewing the file in an editor I get the following output:

```
hello

here i am

<<<<<<< HEAD
i have never been there

a further line

=======
>>>>>>> parent of 35f743c (hello -> hio and newline added)
```

Now here is what I do not understand:
The change from "hello" to "hio" is not indicated as a conflict, whereas the line "i have never been there" is indicated as a conflict.  Why does this happen? I mean: The 35f74 commit changed the first line to "hio" and added the line "i have never been there". The subsequent commit did not touch any of these lines and when I want to undo (revert) these two changes, the first is happily accepted, whereas the second results in a merge conflict.

I guess it would help if someone could explain the mechanism which is underlying the file-comparison in git.

Answer (score 2):

While reverting commit `35f743c` git is expecting line to be

```
i have never been there
```

But the statement is somewhere along the lines of :

```
i have never been there\n
a further line
```

I guess this is a problem only because of **adjacent lines**. The idea being, that adjacent lines are there to provide context to the change and hence to the commit. And had you kept an empty line at the end this would not have shown.

Here is more [reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29276880/why-does-git-produce-a-merge-conflict-when-lines-next-to-each-other-are-changed)

Comment: Thanks. So just to be clear: Had I originally written "i have never been there\n" instead of "i have never been there", then the conflict wouldn't have shown?

Answer (score 1):

Git marks a conflict not only when there are different changes to the same line, but also when there are (necessarily different) changes in *adjacent* lines.

In this case, the conflicting part of change to be reverted is

```
+i have never been there
+
```

which occurs *at the end* of the file.

However, the state into which this reversal is to be integrated is

```
i have never been there

a further line
```

where the text is *not* at the end. Git considers these additional lines as *adjacent*. Hence, the conflict.

Comment: Thanks. But to be sure that I understand it: you mean that the git comparison is not done comparing line x with line x, but it also includes some form of "lookahead"?

Comment: Yes, I think that is reasonable to say. If you start with a file having two lines `a\nb`, then one side makes it `A\nb` and the other makes it `a\nB`, then the merge of both is a conflict although neither line was changed by both sides.